# SQL Select record of the max aggregate

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to select the "job role desc" of the maximum of the aggregates I have achieved. The table looks like follows.

```
[Job Role Description] |  [Number Of Placements]
------------------------------------------------
Training BI                     24
System Analyst                  23
Data Analyst                    24
Data consultant                 25
DB programmer                   24
```

The `job_role_desc` column is from another table joined by `job_role_id`. I used the following code to achieve this.

```
SELECT 
    job_role_dim.job_role_desc AS "Job Role Description" ,
    SUM(fact_accounts.no_of_placements) AS "Number Of Placements" 
FROM 
    fact_accounts 
INNER JOIN 
    job_role_dim ON job_role_dim.job_role_id =  fact_accounts.fk3_job_role_id 
GROUP BY 
    job_role_dim.job_role_desc
```

How can I modify the above code to only display the `job_role_desc` that has the maximum number of placements? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT ja.*
FROM (SELECT j.job_role_desc AS "Job Role Description" ,   
             SUM(a.no_of_placements) AS "Number Of Placements",
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(a.no_of_placements) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM fact_accounts a INNER JOIN
           job_role_dim j
           ON j.job_role_id = a.fk3_job_role_id
      GROUP BY j.job_role_desc
     ) ja
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If you want all versions with the maximum, then use `dense_rank()` or `rank()`.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to select only the job_role_desc without no_of_placements or the row_number?

Comment: @DazedNConfused . . . Yes, just put the columns you want in the outer `select` instead of `*`.